# Ubuntu 16.04 - Time shown by clock widget in the task bar is incorrect

Tags: systemd, locale, clock, timezone

I have already manually setup some symlinks that should guarantee system time to be according to the locale I want, namely

```
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Canada/Eastern /etc/localtime
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Canada/Eastern /etc/timezone
```

Also, if I check the system time using `date`, it display the correct local time. However, the clock widget is 2 hours off both in Lightdm and within Unity.

This installs is actually sitting on a server and serves it using PXE/NFS. So, I can only make change through a chroot environment on the server. This is unfortunate as most systemd's commands refuses to run in a chroot environment. Any idea how I can get the clock back in sync with the system's local time?

As a funny anomaly, doing a `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` and selecting 'America/Montreal' yields the following output:

```
Current default time zone: 'America/Montreal'
Local time is now:      Fri Jun 17 17:49:29 UTC 2016.
Universal Time is now:  Fri Jun 17 17:49:29 UTC 2016.
```

However this is 4 hours off, not the 2 hours difference I notice on the widget, so it is probably not related...